# Selection sort for linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, selection-sort

We have seen in class how selection sort algorithm works on arrays data structure. In this lab we will practice how selection sort can be performed on a linked list ADT.
1. Convert the following selection sort pseudo-code to perform the sort in ascending order. (selectionSort_asc function)
a. Find the node with the minimum value in the linked list of length n
b. Append the min node in a new result linked list
c. Delete min from original linked list
d. Repeat steps a-c until the original linked list is empty
e. Return the result linked list
2. Convert the following selection-sort pseudo-code to perform the sort in descending order. (selectionSort_desc function)
a. Find the node with the maximum value in the linked list of length n
b. Append the max node in a new result linked list
c. Delete max from original linked list
d. Repeat steps a-c until the original linked list is empty
e. Return the result linked list

I tried this code below but it does not give me the right output.

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node head = initializeList("ilovedata"); 
        System.out.println("\n List Before selectionSort_asc");
        printList(head);
        head = selectionSort_asc(head);
        System.out.println("\n List After selectionSort_asc");
        printList(head);
        // Expected answer: -> a -> a -> d -> e -> i -> l -> o -> t -> v
        head = initializeList("ilovedata"); 
        System.out.println("\n List Before selectionSort_desc");
        printList(head);
        head = selectionSort_desc(head);
        System.out.println("\n List After selectionSort_desc");
        printList(head);
        // Expected answer: -> v -> t -> o -> l -> i -> e -> d -> a -> a
        }
        public static Node selectionSort_asc(Node head){ 
            Node result = null;

            Node curr, prev, min;
            while(head!=null) {
                curr = head;
                prev = null;
                min = head;
                while(curr.next!=null) {
                    curr = curr.next;
                    if(curr.item<min.item) {
                        prev = min;
                        min = curr;
                    }
                }
                //append the min at the end of result list
                Node add_min = new Node(min.item);
                if(result==null)
                    result = add_min;
                else {
                    Node last = result;
                    while(last.next!=null) {
                        last = last.next;
                    }
                    last.next = add_min;
                }
                //delete the min node form original list    
                if(min==head) {
                    head = head.next;
                }
                else if(min.next==null){
                    prev.next = null;
                }else {
                    prev.next = prev.next.next;
                    min.next = null;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        public static Node selectionSort_desc(Node head){ 
            Node result = null;

            Node curr, prev, max;           
            while(head!=null) {
                curr = head;
                prev = null;
                max = head;
                //find out the max node
                while(curr.next!=null) {
                    curr = curr.next;
                    if(curr.item>max.item) {
                        prev = max;
                        max = curr;
                    }
                }
                //add max to the end of result list             
                Node add_max = new Node(max.item);
                if(result==null) {
                    result = add_max;
                }
                else {
                    Node last = result;
                    while(last.next!=null) {
                        last = last.next;
                    }
                    last.next = add_max;
                }
                //delete min from original list
                if(max == head) {
                    head = head.next;
                }
                else if(max.next==null){
                    prev.next = null;
                }
                else {
                    prev.next = max.next;
                    max.next = null;
                }

            }           
            return result;
        }
        // Method that takes a string and insert its characters into a linked list
        public static Node initializeList(String str){ 
            Node head= new Node(str.charAt(0)),cur; 
            int i;
            for(cur= head,i=1;i<str.length();i++,cur=cur.next){ 
                cur.next = new Node(str.charAt(i));
            }       
            return head;
        }
        // Method for printing linked list 
        public static void printList(Node head){
               Node cur = head;
               if(head==null) 
                   System.out.print("<EMPTY>"); 
               for(;cur!=null;cur=cur.next){
                   System.out.print("-> "+cur.item+" ");
               }
        }
}
```

Comment: The output of this code is: List Before selectionSort_asc
-> i -> l -> o -> v -> e -> d -> a -> t -> a 
 List After selectionSort_asc
-> a -> a -> d -> e -> i 
 List Before selectionSort_desc
-> i -> l -> o -> v -> e -> d -> a -> t -> a 
 List After selectionSort_desc
-> v -> t -> o -> l -> i -> a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the assigning of your `prev` variable in these snippets of code

```
public static Node selectionSort_asc(Node head){ 
...
    if(curr.item><min.item) {
        prev = min;
        min = curr;
    }
...
}

public static Node selectionSort_desc(Node head){ 
...
    if(curr.item>max.item) {
        prev = max;
        max = curr;
    }
...
}
```

You're currently assigning `prev` to the old `min` and the old `max`, but according to the design of your code, you want `prev` to be pointing to the node before the new `min` and new `max` with the way you're removing the `min` node from the original linked list. My recommendation is to keep another set of variables called `beforeMin` and `beforeMax` and set these equal to the current value of `prev` when you find a new minimum or maximum. In addition to this, you should also update your `prev` variable in each iteration of the while loop just like you're doing to `curr`. Here's how it'll look like for `selectionSort_asc` and you can figure out how to adjust your descending method to mirror it:

```
public static Node selectionSort_asc(Node head){ 
    Node result = null;

    Node curr, prev, min, beforeMin;
    while(head!=null) {
        curr = head;
        prev = null;
        min = head;
        beforeMin = prev; // new variable
        while(curr.next!=null) {
            prev = curr; // update prev with each iteration
            curr = curr.next;
            if(curr.item<min.item) {
                beforeMin = prev; // variable points to the node before the min node
                min = curr;
            }
        }
        //append the min at the end of result list
        Node add_min = new Node(min.item);
        if(result==null)
            result = add_min;
        else {
            Node last = result;
            while(last.next!=null) {
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next = add_min;
        }
        //delete the min node form original list    
        if(min==head) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        else if(min.next==null){
            beforeMin.next = null; // no more prev here
        }else {
            beforeMin.next = beforeMin.next.next; // notice how beforeMin is used now
            min.next = null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much for your help! My code is working properly now.

Comment: @AndrewWen anytime, glad it helped!